# How to parameterize waiting-time in Oracle Query "Select-For-Update"

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters, odp.net

In my program i run a "select for update"-Query like this:

```
OracleConnection con = GenerateConnection();

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = :COL2 AND rownum = 1 FOR UPDATE WAIT 2";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":COL2 ", "some value"));

string myValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

This works pretty well. Now i want to parameterize the time to wait to get the lock (Some integrationstests which shall wait a little longer, because of the slower test-environment).

Becuase of this i tried this one:

```
OracleConnection con = GenerateConnection();

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = :COL2 AND rownum = 1 FOR UPDATE WAIT :WAITFOR";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":COL2 ", "some value"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":WAITFOR", 2));

string myValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Unfortunately i get this:

> ORA-30005: missing or invalid WAIT interval

My Question:

Do i have to do a `String.Format()` or did i something wrong?

Comment: You can't parameterize what doesn't accept parameters. Why use `FOR UPDATE` at all though? Do you really want to *lock* that row? Why not use a transaction in that case? Even better, why not use optimistic concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parametrize `WAIT` because it requires **integer literal**. You could build your query with string concatenation or interpolation:

```
int waitfor = 2;
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = :COL2 AND rownum = 1 FOR UPDATE WAIT {waitfor}";
```

Please note that this technique is workaround(possible SQL Injection for user input). It should be used only when there is no other option and the parameter cannot be tampered by user or is properly sanitized.

Comment: I know this one. Seems a little like a `String.Format()`. But you know: The biggest enemy of a programmer is another programmer. Is there no way to tell the command that it should wait or somthing?

Comment: @kara At least for DDL you could set it on session level [DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams068.htm#REFRN10267). I am not sure if something similar exists for DML